# What is the request_id in sys.dm_exec_requests and how does it change?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dmv

According to MSDN, the request_id in `sys.dm_exec_requests` is the

> "ID of the request. Unique in the context of the session. Is not
>   nullable."

It always appears to be 0, from casual observation.

Can someone tell me how, for a given session, this id can ever be more than 0? Is it possible to reproduce this with some sql?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can someone tell me how, for a given session, this id can ever be more
>   than 0? Is it possible to reproduce this with some sql?

The request_id other than zero indicates a connection with [Multiple Active Result Sets (MARS)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h32h3abf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) enabled.  With MARS, a single connection may have multiple active statements, with statement execution interleaved.

From SSMS, open a new query window connection specifying `MultipleActiveResultSets=True`under "Options-->Additional Connection Parameters".  Then run the query below in the window.  You should see a non-zero request_id value.

```
SELECT * 
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests
WHERE session_id = @@SPID;
```